# Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit Binder Routing Key always '#'

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-rabbit

Version: Spring Boot: 1.4.2.RELEASE
Spring Cloud Deps: Brixton.SR7

Here is my application.properties of a processor app.

```
logging.level.=DEBUG
server.port=0
logging.file=traveller-events-processor.log
server.port=0
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bindingRoutingKey='aa'
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bindingRoutingKey=aa
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.bindQueue=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.routing-key='aa'
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.routingKey='aa'
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=events-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=eventconsumersgroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=work.out
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.contentType=text/plain
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.binder=rabbit
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.group=traveller-events-output-group
```

When I start this app, events-exchange is created as expected and bound to a queue named: events-exchange.eventconsumersgroup (which is also ok). But the routingKey is always '#'. I've tried with all the options I have fished from various documentations. Am I missing something here?

I want this app to only subscribe to certain messages (which I want to achieve via the routing key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that Brixton.SR7 uses 1.0.2.RELEASE of Spring Cloud Stream and I don't seem to find the `routingKey` as a Rabbit consumer property. Do you want to upgrade to Spring Cloud Camden release or the latest one so that you can try using the consumer property: `bindingRoutingKey` as mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties)

Comment: Cheers! It's a version lag issue.